# Can't figure out the equation in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help, I can't figure out the equation to solve a real-world problem.

Here is the case:  Each employee can pick up the customer if he/she comes to store first (first come first serve).  If he/she make >=12 dollars more than other employees, then rotate to next employee that comes after. If he/she makes < 12 dollars, then continue picking up the next customer.

[image: Excel image]

```
Come to store:   -----1st  -----    2nd  ----  3rd   ------     4th    -----    5th   ----     6th   ---   7th 

Employee name: Apple  --  Bear  --  Conny  --    Donny  --    Elvis   --   Fell     -- Gith

Total $: ---------------33   -----    28   -------     20   -------      23  -------      22   ----     15  ----      2

Who turns next?   
It should be: -------- 2nd   ---    3rd  ------    4th    ------     5th  ------    6th ----      7th    -   1st
```

As you can see, It is Gith turn to pick up the next customer, Gith only made 2 dollars, the difference is >=12 dollars between Gith and other employees. 
It is Apple turn after Gith even though Apple made more than Fell >=12 dollars, but because other employees in between like Conny Donny Elvis who doesn't make >=12 dollars more than Fell, so it is Apple turn.

How can I come up with an equation that could solve this situation?

Comment: According to _"If he/she makes < 12 dollars, then continue picking up the next customer."_ .. Gith only made 2 dollars.. so the next customer is supposed to be attended by Gith.. not Apple.

Comment: That is true, as I mentioned that Apple takes the second turn after Gith

Comment: If in the next sale, Gith only made 10 dollars.. will it be sufficient to pass to Apple?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one answer.  Fill in C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4 with the following to know if you should skip them:  (C3 at the start should be the cell right above, ie D4,E4 etc..)

```
=IF(C3>(LARGE($C3:$I3,2)+12),"skip","")
```

Then fill in C5 with the following to know if someone is jumping out of order:

```
=IF(SMALL(C3:I3,1)<(SMALL(C3:I3,2)-12),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2+(MATCH(SMALL(C3:I3,1),C3:I3,0)))),"Next non-skip")
```

What we don't know:  Who served someone last?

*Edit: return name of person jumping out of order rather than dollar amount.*

Comment: Thank you for helping, but if I change the amount in Fell to 3 dollars.  Should it be Fell first then Gith second?  I only get "Next non-skip" as a result instead of Fell.  My goal is to display all the employee names from first to last

Comment: My formula is working on if they made less than 12 dollars _than anyone else_.  When changing Fell to 3, that no longer holds true.  I would say that Gith then Fell.  But for a logic formula we would need to determine if the condition is "making 12 dollars less than _anyone_ else" or making 12 dollars less than _everyone_ else" or some number of people in the middle.  Fell @ 15 is already 12 less than Apple and Bear.

Comment: =IF(SMALL($C3:$I3,1)<(SMALL($C3:$I3,2)-11),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2+(MATCH(SMALL($C3:$I3,1),$C3:$I3,0)))),"Next non-skip")

Comment: looks like my answer above had a double equals "==" at the start.  With one equal sign it looks to work on my side.

Comment: =IF(SMALL($C3:$I3,1)<(SMALL($C3:$I3,2)-11),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2+(MATCH(SMALL($C3:$I3,1),$C3:$I3,0)))),"Next non-skip"), You are right, I change 12 to 11 to fit my need,  and plus  =IF(SMALL($C3:$I3,2)<(SMALL($C3:$I3,3)-11),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2+(MATCH(SMALL($C3:$I3,2),$C3:$I3,0)))),"Next non-skip")  to the next cell inorder to display Fell.   If all the name can't be displayed, is there a way to display the number as I have mentioned above?  Ex. 1, 2 3, 4 relative to who picks up the customer first, second, third?  I'm able to link the number to the name.  If that's easier to show

Comment: If the name of the last person to serve is in C8, then our formula for next to serve is (with 7 employees):  =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,IF(SMALL($C3:$I3,1)<(SMALL($C3:$I3,2)-11),2+(MATCH(SMALL($C3:$I3,1),$C3:$I3,0)),IF(2+MATCH(C8,C2:I2,0)+1>9,2+MATCH(C8,C2:I2,0)+1-7,2+MATCH(C8,C2:I2,0)+1))))  Then propagate that out to the next columns as you have the previous formula.  I moved the indirect out of the if statement in this one to avoid entering it twice.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you apply C8.  If Fell make 3 dollars and Gith make 2 dollars, the last employee to serve would be Elvis (G2).  I put the jumping out formula in C5 to I5, and formula next to serve is in C6 to I6.  I don't understand the next to serve part, espcially when you say C8.  The last person to serve is constantly changing as employees entering their money.  Please elaborate.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following your shared table..

Fill in there labels :

```
B6  ---->  currentNo :
B7  ---->  nextNo :
B9  ---->  Next Name :
```

Then these formulas :

```
C6  ---->  =MATCH(C2,{"Apple","Bear","Conny","Donny","Elvis","Fell","Gith"},0)
C7  ---->  =IF(C3>=12,IF((C6+1)=8,1,C6+1),C6)
C9  ---->  =INDEX({"Apple","Bear","Conny","Donny","Elvis","Fell","Gith"},C7)
D2  ---->  =C9
```

Then drag all right-wards.

Done.  Hope it helps. ( :